# Building a data structure - Hashes of Hashes of Hashes of Arrays

Tags: ruby, parsing, text, transformation, text-parsing

This week at work I had the challenge of parsing a specific file format
that contains IP ranges categorized by different Sites, Areas and
Regions.
Basically I needed a script to load all this location information into a
data structure, that would allow me an easy way of obtaining all the IPs
of sites, areas or regions for a later transformation.

```
Required data structure:
 data[Region][Area][Site] -> IPs
       Hash   Hash  Hash   Array
```

I would like to know if the function “processLocations” could be
optimized or if there exists a simpler way of achieving the desired data
structure. specially in the creation of the "Hashes of Hashes of Hashes of Arrays" region variable.

Hope this can also help someone else in the same situation, so here is a my current working copy:

```
require 'pp'

# Function that processes the content of the locations file and returns
the following structure:
#
# data[Region][Area][Site] -> IPs
#       Hash   Hash  Hash   Array
#
def processLocations (lines)
  sites = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []} # HashOFArray
  area = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc)} # HashOFHash
  region = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc)} # HashOFHash

  lines.each do |line|
    next if lines =~ /^#.*/

    # Process IPs range section
    if line =~ /(.*)=([\d|\-|\.]+)/
      #puts "IP: #{$1} - #{$2}"
      sites[$1.chomp.capitalize] << $2
    end

    # Process area section
    if line =~ /(.*)\.area=(.*)/i
      #puts "Area: #{$1} - #{$2}"
      if sites.has_key?($1.chomp.capitalize)

        if (area.has_key?($2.chomp.capitalize) &
area[$2.chomp.capitalize].has_key?($1.chomp.capitalize))
          # The hash exists
          #puts "Adding to an existing hash key more IPs elements to the
array"
          area[$2.chomp.capitalize][$1.chomp.capitalize] <<
sites[$1.chomp.capitalize]
       else
          # The hash does not exist
          #puts "Adding new hash key with new array"
          area[$2.chomp.capitalize][$1.chomp.capitalize] =
sites[$1.chomp.capitalize]
        end

        # Clean site hash
        sites = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []} # HashOFArray
      end
    end

    # Process region section
    if line =~ /(.*)\.region=(.*)/i
      #puts "Region: #{$1} - #{$2}"
      if area.has_key?($1.chomp.capitalize)
        tmp = Hash.new
        tmp = area.dup

        region[$2.chomp.capitalize][$1.chomp.capitalize] =
tmp[$1.chomp.capitalize]
      end
    end
  end
  return region
end

##############
#  MAIN

f = File.open(DATA)
 lines = f.readlines
f.close
data = processLocations(lines)

puts "+data---------------------------------------------------------"
pp data

puts "+data['Asia']-------------------------------------------------"
pp data['Asia']

puts "+data['Asia']['Australia']------------------------------------"
pp data['Asia']['Australia']

puts "+data['Europe-middle east-africa']['France']['Paris']---------"
pp data['Europe-middle east-africa']['France']['Paris']


__END__
Alexandria (ALH)=192.168.6.0-192.168.6.127
Alexandria (ALH).area=Australia
Australia.region=Asia

Altona=192.168.1.192-192.168.1.255
Altona=192.168.2.192-192.168.2.255
Altona.area=Australia

TOKYO VPN=192.168.3.192-192.168.3.255
TOKYO VPN.area=JAPAN
JAPAN.region=Asia

Paris=192.168.4.192-192.168.4.255
Paris.area=France

Rennes=192.168.5.192-192.168.5.255
Rennes.area=France
France.region=EUROPE-MIDDLE EAST-AFRICA
```

Example output:

```
# ruby ruby_help.rb
+data---------------------------------------------------------
{"Asia"=>
  {"Australia"=>
    {"Alexandria (alh)"=>["192.168.6.0-192.168.6.127"],
     "Altona"=>["192.168.1.192-192.168.1.255",
"192.168.2.192-192.168.2.255"]},
   "Japan"=>{"Tokyo vpn"=>["192.168.3.192-192.168.3.255"]}},
 "Europe-middle east-africa"=>
  {"France"=>
    {"Paris"=>["192.168.4.192-192.168.4.255"],
     "Rennes"=>["192.168.5.192-192.168.5.255"]}}}
+data['Asia']-------------------------------------------------
{"Australia"=>
  {"Alexandria (alh)"=>["192.168.6.0-192.168.6.127"],
   "Altona"=>["192.168.1.192-192.168.1.255",
"192.168.2.192-192.168.2.255"]},
 "Japan"=>{"Tokyo vpn"=>["192.168.3.192-192.168.3.255"]}}
+data['Asia']['Australia']------------------------------------
{"Alexandria (alh)"=>["192.168.6.0-192.168.6.127"],
 "Altona"=>["192.168.1.192-192.168.1.255",
"192.168.2.192-192.168.2.255"]}
+data['Europe-middle east-africa']['France']['Paris']---------
["192.168.4.192-192.168.4.255"]
```

Regards and thanks in advance for any suggestions,

Sebastian YEPES

Comment: Ruby does have classes you know, you don't have to jam everything into Hashes and Arrays. You could probably push a lot of that logic into small custom classes and then you wouldn't have such a frighteningly long `processLocations` method.

Comment: You have a couple of bugs... & should be &&

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mu that you could build some classes, but I think this should work:

```
def processLocations (lines)
  sites     = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
  areas     = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = {}}
  regions   = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = {}}

  lines.each do |line|

  case line
    # Process IPs range section
    when /(.*)=([\d|\-|\.]+)/
      sites[$1.chomp.capitalize] << $2
    # Process area section
    when /(.*)\.area=(.*)/i
      site_key, area = $1.chomp.capitalize, areas[$2.chomp.capitalize]
      area[site_key] = sites[site_key]
    # Process region section
    when /(.*)\.region=(.*)/i
      area_key, region = $1.chomp.capitalize, regions[$2.chomp.capitalize]
      region[area_key] = areas[area_key]
    when /^#.*/ # do nothing
    else
      # error?
    end
  end
  regions
end
```